# Accessing Active Directory from ASP.net App

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, active-directory

I have sections of my asp.net 4 MVC application that access Active Directory to check for Group Membership.  When I a run the site from my computer, it works fine since I am a domain admin. When I run the site from a test computer under a standard user, I get a DirectoryServicesCOM error when trying to access AD.  Obviously it's a permissions issue.

My question is, where and what within IIS do I tell to access AD as a specific account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you using to access AD? I'm assuming `System.DirectoryServices`

What account is you app pool running as & what version of IIS? Assuming IIS7 or greater, you're probably using `AppPoolIdentity` which means you're accessing AD as anonymous user. Change the identity to `NetworkService` & it should use the machine account of your web server.

If you need privileges to do activities, then you'll need to use a specific account. If you're  using `AccountManagement` Objects, then specify the credentials in a context class. If you're using classes in `Protocols`, then you do it using the connection. MSDN & Google have plenty of examples.

You should understand the security implications of the approach you use, as with all things security related.